# Using symbolic links to add a folder to the path on macOS

Tags: macos, mac, shell, symbolic-link, golang

macOS 10.12.6

Hello, I have a Golang installation on an Apple Mac and I would like to make the files in my $GOBIN folder (~/code/go/bin) searchable from anywhere.

I'm aware that I could simply add that folder to my $PATH, but in the interests of keeping my `.zshrc` nice and clean, I am trying to find a way of using symbolic links (`ln`) to achieve this.

Can anyone shed some light on this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's another way, cleanly at least, than adding it your ~/.zshrc

I don't know .zshrc syntax, but this works in bash:

`if [ -d "$GOBIN" ]; then
   PATH="$PATH:$GOBIN";
fi`